# OpenCL data parallel summation into a variable

Tags: c++, arrays, sum, opencl

Is it possible to use the opencl data parallel kernel to sum vector of size N, without doing the partial sum trick?

Say that if you have access to 16 work items and your vector is of size 16. Wouldn't it not be possible to just have a kernel doing the following

```
    __kernel void summation(__global float* input, __global float* sum)
{
    int idx = get_global_id(0);

    sum[0] += input[idx];
}
```

When I've tried this, the sum variable doesn't get updated, but only overwritten. I've read something about using barriers, and i tried inserting a barrier before the summation above, it does update the variable somehow, but it doesn't reproduce the correct sum.

Comment: Overwritten but not updated ? What does that even mean to you ?
By the way this kind of operation is exactly what cannot be done in parallel, what if sum[0] get read by one work item just before being written by another ? the first change will just go to trash

Comment: @HubertApplebaum Thanks for the tip! Yeah I know that for a vector of size 16 it seems to not be worth the trouble to use OpenCL. I was just curious if the concept would work. And I have nothing against reductions, just thought that the coding would be less and easier to read?

Comment: @Guiroux: Sorry if I was a bit unclear. What I meant with overwritten is what you refer to as the first change will just go to trash.

I guess that the reduction is the safest and fastest way to do it, and to ignore this way of thinking? Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try to explain why `sum[0]` is overwritten rather than updated.

In your case of 16 work items, there are 16 threads which are running simultaneously. Now `sum[0]` is a single memory location which is shared by all of the threads, and the line `sum[0] += input[idx]` is run by each of the 16 threads, simultaneously.

Now the instruction `sum[0] += input[idx]` (I think) expands performs a read of `sum[0]`, then adds `input[idx]` to that before writing the result back to `sum[0]`.

There will will be a [data race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) as multiple threads are reading from and writing to the same shared memory location. So what might happen is:

- All threads may read the value of `sum[0]` before any other thread
  writes their updated result back to `sum[0]`, in which case the final
  result of `sum[0]` would be the value of `input[idx]` of the thread
  which executed the slowest. Since this will be different each time,
  if you run the example multiple times you should see different
  results.
- Or, one thread may execute slightly more slowly, in which case
  another thread may have already written an updated result back to
  `sum[0]` before this slow thread reads `sum[0]`, in which case there
  will be an addition using the values of more than one thread, but not
  all threads.

So how can you avoid this?

**Option 1 - Atomics (Worse Option):**

You can use [atomics](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-opencl-20-atomics) to force all threads to block if another thread is performing an operation on the shared memory location, but this obviously results in a loss of performance since you are making the parallel process serial (and incurring the costs of parallelisation -- such as moving memory between the host and the device and creating the threads).

**Option 2 - Reduction (Better Option):**

The best solution would be to reduce the array, since you can use the parallelism most effectively, and can give O(log(N)) performance. Here is a good overview of reduction using OpenCL : [Reduction Example](http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/articles-whitepapers/opencl-optimization-case-study-simple-reductions/).

Comment: I suspected it might be the issue you just described. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Option 3 (and worst of all)

```
    __kernel void summation(__global float* input, __global float* sum)
{
    int idx = get_global_id(0);
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
    {
        barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE| CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
        if(idx==j)
         sum[0] += input[idx];
        else
         doOtherWorkWhileSingleCoreSums();

    }
}
```

using a mainstream gpu, this should sum all of them as slow as a pentium mmx . This is just like computing on  a single core and giving other cores other jobs but in a slower way.

A cpu device could be better than gpu for this kind.